# Array List Adapter - How to instantiate an Object?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to write a program to display a set of values from a database on my android. Using php connection.

My question is

**ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(this, R.id.Menu);**

or

**listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, R.id.Menu, menuitems));**

both codes give me the same error. ***Cannot instantiate the type ListAdapter.***

My relevant imports are :

- android.widget.AdapterView
- android.widget.ListAdapter
- android.widget.ListView import
- android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener import
- android.widget.ArrayAdapter

why is this happening ? Why I can't instantiate the required object ? What am I doing wrong ?
please help

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListAdapter` is an interface. In Java, you need to instantiate a concrete class. A concrete class serves as a bridge between the ListView and the data to be displayed; it is responsible (among other things) for packaging up the data as a row View for the ListView to use. Pick the concrete class that corresponds to how your data is organized. (It might be an `ArrayAdapter<YourDataType>`, a `CursorAdapter`, another of the classes listed in the docs, or even something of your own design.)

Answer (score 0):

ListAdapter is an interface try using one of its implementation class e.g SimpleCursorAdapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a concrete class to use adapter, ListAdapter is an interface, so you need to either use SimpleArrayAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter like class, or impolement the ListInterface in a class and use that class to instantiate ListAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create adapter from `android.widget.ListAdapter`, then error is self explained . create `ArrayAdapter/BaseAdapter` instead.

else if `ListAdapter` is your own class remove `import android.widget.ListAdapter` and add you import like `import com.yourpackage.ListAdapter`